# Erazor effect on UIView

Tags: ios, core-animation, core-graphics

Consider 2 views; the opaque (gray) one covers the one with graphics. I want to get an effect, such as if a erazer was sliding along a path with a certain speed, and erazing opaque color into transparent, uncovering the underlaying graphics view (see image).

The only approach i could come up with, is to have considerably many small views instead of the opaque view, and animate aplhas of those. But this seems dumb and heavy solution.

I never had any sserious experience with CoreGraphics nor with CoreAnimation, and reading docs on those can be confusing for a noob. So im asking if someone could give me a nudge, what to read and where to dig. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you want eraser to move along a predefined path (a `CGPath` or `UIBezierPath`), or to follow the user's touch?

Comment: @robmayoff, no user touch, predefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to turn your thinking around.  Don't imagine erasing gray to reveal the image.  Imagine drawing the image on top of the gray.

The way you do this is you put the gray view behind the image view, and you use a `CAShapeLayer` as the image view's layer mask.  Set your “eraser” path as the shape layer's `path`.  Set the shape layer's `lineWidth` to whatever width you like.  Set its `fillColor` to `[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor`.

If you do that, you'll see the image along the path and gray elsewhere.

To animate the movement of the “eraser”, add a `CABasicAnimation` to the shape layer.  Animate the shape layer's `strokeEnd` property from `@0.0f` to `@1.0f`.

Comment: This is great! Thank you for sharing. Dont know if i can pull it off that easy, but its great for a start. Thanks again.

Comment: Why won't that just draw a wide white line?  How will it reveal the image?

Comment: @SteveWaddicor Read about [“Mask Properties” in the *Core Animation Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/LayerStyleProperties/LayerStyleProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH10-SW21).

Answer (score 2):

Simply draw on the grey view with [UIColor clearColor];  Wherever a transparent color like that appears, it will show the underlying view.

You'll have to set the view with the grey as opaque=NO first.  This won't make the grey view invisible, it's just a hint to iOS that there are transparent parts to it.